# I want to auto cursor when I input text in multiple textbox and save to database

Tags: asp.net

I'm beginner about ASP.NET MVC Framework.
I have some problem please help me...

here is example
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMjJp.png
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSi4U.png

I want to auto cursor when I input text in multiple textbox and
i want to save this data to database as "1222233333445"

*This project about ASP.NET MVC4 Web Application

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to join all numbers as one using javascript:

```
function UpdateNumber() {
var num1 = document.getElementById(num1ClientID);
var num2 = document.getElementById(num2ClientID);
var num3 = document.getElementById(num3ClientID);
var num4 = document.getElementById(num4ClientID);
var fullnum = num1.value + num2.value + num3.value + num4.value;
ex.value = fullnum;
}
```

ex is the label on your page where you display the whole number. You can call UpdateNumber() on the onkeyup event of each of your text boxes. Below is a code example for num1 (call UpdateNumber() for all textboxes).

```
<input id="num1ClientID" type="text" onkeyup="UpdateNumber();" name="num1ClientID">
```

In your code behind, get the value of ex.